# Passing multiple lists of arguments through rlang quosures and dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

Objective: write a function that will take a data frame as its first
argument, and then two additional arguments, lists of argments, passed to
`dplyr::select` such that the function will return two data frames.

Here is a working example

```
my_select <- function(.data, df1, df2) {
  DF1 <- dplyr::select(.data, rlang::UQS(df1))
  DF2 <- dplyr::select(.data, rlang::UQS(df2))
  list(DF1 = DF1, DF2 = DF2)
}

working_eg <-
  my_select(mtcars,
          df1 = alist(dplyr::contains("r"), dplyr::matches("^.p.*")),
          df2 = alist(disp))

str(working_eg, max.length = 1L)

## List of 2
##  $ DF1:'data.frame': 32 obs. of  5 variables:
##   ..$ drat: num [1:32] 3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
##   ..$ gear: num [1:32] 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
##   ..$ carb: num [1:32] 4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
##   ..$ mpg : num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
##   ..$ hp  : num [1:32] 110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
##  $ DF2:'data.frame': 32 obs. of  1 variable:
##   ..$ disp: num [1:32] 160 160 108 258 360 ...
```

I would prefer that the argments `df1` and `df2` take a `list` not a `alist`.
however, the function `my_select` will fail if the arguments are `list`

```
my_select(mtcars,
          df1 = list(dplyr::contains("r"), dplyr::matches("^.p.*")),
          df2 = list(disp))
## Error: Variable context not set
```

I don't want to ask end users to use `alist`, if possible, as I don't have a
good way to test that `alist` was used to pass arguments instead of `list`.

I've tried several combinations of `rlang::UQ`, `rlang::UQE`, `rlang::UQS`
with `rlang::quo`, `rlang::enquos`, and `rlang::quos` to fix this.  What I
thought was the best approach was:

```
my_select2 <- function(.data, df1, df2) {
  DF1 <- dplyr::select(.data, rlang::UQS(rlang::quos(df1)))
  DF2 <- dplyr::select(.data, rlang::UQS(rlang::quos(df2)))
  list(DF1 = DF1, DF2 = DF2)
}

my_select2(mtcars,
          df1 = list(dplyr::contains("r"), dplyr::matches("^.p.*")),
          df2 = list(disp))
## Error: `df1` must resolve to integer column positions, not a list
```

Is there a way to use the [rlang](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rlang)
package with [dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/package=dplyr) so that the
syntax of `my_select2` will return the same object as `my_select` does when
arguments are passed via `alist`?

```
packageVersion("dplyr")
# [1] ‘0.7.4’
packageVersion("rlang")
# [1] ‘0.1.2’
```

Comment: What if someone tries to do `x <- list(dplyr::contains("r"), dplyr::matches("^.p.*")); y<- list(disp); my_select2(mtcars, x, y)` because then you are really running into trouble because those first assignments will never work with `list()` but would work with `alist()`.

Comment: Since you are using `dplyr()`, you should probably be using `vars()` here instead of `list()` or `alist()` anyway. This is consistent with how it's used in the rest of the package.

Comment: I was so focused on the changes in `dplyr (>= 0.7.0)` and `rlang` that I forgot about `dplyr::vars()`.  That was the answer.  Thank you, @MrFlick.  I'll post the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MrFlick's comment was the reminder I needed to solve the problem and improve the api.

```
my_select3 <- function(.data, df1, df2) {
  DF1 <- dplyr::select(.data, rlang::UQS((df1)))
  DF2 <- dplyr::select(.data, rlang::UQS((df2)))
  list(DF1 = DF1, DF2 = DF2)
}

working_eg2 <-
  my_select3(mtcars,
            df1 = dplyr::vars(dplyr::contains("r"), dplyr::matches("^.p.*")),
            df2 = dplyr::vars(disp))

all.equal(working_eg, working_eg2)
# [1] TRUE
```